# How to get the data from text boxes of checked rows on Alert box in Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, web

I want to view all the rows which are checked on m alert box whenever i press the button but i am doing something wrong here

Javascript for Adding rows

```
 $("#add").click(function () {
    $("#myTable").last().append("<tr><td width='5%'><input type='checkbox'>                                       
   </td><td><input type='text' id='1stid'>  
  </td><td><input type='text' id='2ndid'></td><td><input type='text'id='3rdid'></td></tr>");
 });
```

I also did this but now the alert box is empty

```
$("#view").click(function () {
  $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked');
    var n=$(this).closest('tr').text();
    alert(n);
});
```

My HTML

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Project.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <button id="add">Add</button>  <button id="deleteLast">Remove </button> <button id="delete"> Remove All</button> <button id="view">View</button>

        <table class="table table-bordered" id="myTable">
            <tr>
                <th width="5%"></th>
                <th>First name</th>
                <th>Last name</th>
                <th>Profession</th>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Project.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please post your HTML code so we have a bit more context.

Comment: @gyre html code is only have 4 buttons and one simple row i am adding rows dynamically with my buttons and deleting them now i am stuck at this the button of view have id (#view)

Comment: still best to post an example on jsfiddle so people can more readily test and see the code... unless you don't mind someone, who can potentially solve your problem, skip your question because they couldn't be bothered doing the jsfiddle for you.

Comment: @A.Lau didnt used jsfiddle before

Comment: Go here https://jsfiddle.net/ put up your code to simulate your problem. Save it (in the top left area) then link us the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the `$("input[type='checkbox']:checked")` will return an array/list of elements, use jQuery's `each` method, `$("input[type='checkbox']:checked").each(...)` to iterate through the result

```js
$("#view").click(function() {
  $("input[type='checkbox']:checked").each(function(index) {    
       $('td input[type=text]', $(this).closest('tr')).each(function(index2) {
           
           alert( $(this).val() );
           
      });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
  <tr class="test">
    <td width='5%'>
      <input type='checkbox'>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type='text' id='11stid' value="1 first">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type='text' id='12ndid' value="1 second">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type='text' id='13rdid' value="1 third">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width='5%'>
      <input type='checkbox'>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type='text' id='21stid' value="2 first">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type='text' id='22ndid' value="2 second">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type='text' id='23rdid' value="2 third">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width='5%'>
      <input type='checkbox'>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type='text' id='31stid' value="3 first">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type='text' id='32ndid' value="3 second">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type='text' id='33rdid' value="3 third">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<button id="view">Checked</button>
```

Comment: @AhsanAli As the above work, do you mean it does not work in your code?

Comment: yes bro its just show "on" on every alert box @LGSon

Comment: @AhsanAli Well, then you must have missed something from my code sample or in how you applied it. Update your question with the relevant markup and I'll have a look

Comment: i want to show the other 3 text boxes data sorry i forgot to mention that before the check box i check i want to show the data of each text of that td on alert @LGSon

Comment: @AhsanAli Ok, just update your question with the markup

Comment: @AhsanAli Can't see any html? ... need that

Comment: posted the html file please take a look @LGSon

Comment: @AhsanAli Can still not see any table cells containing text boxes and input checkboxes

Comment: posted the Javascript for adding rows @LGSon

Comment: @AhsanAli Updated my answer

Comment: Thankss bro you saved my life @LGSon

Comment: @AhsanAli Made one more update ... optimized the inner query